# Why does Eclipse update the workbench.xmi file every five minutes?

Tags: eclipse

I have `DropBox` on my machine at home and on my work PC.  I also have Eclipse installed on my home PC.  I put all of the workspace files in my DropBox account for a few different reasons.

Anyway, at work, I notice that DropBox notifies me every 5 minutes that the `workbench.xmi` file has been updated.  I realized that I left Eclipse running at home.  This is very annoying.

Upon inspection, it looks like Eclipse is changing the ID's of all (or most) of the components.  Doing a diff on the file every 5 minutes revealed this.

Is there a way to prevent Eclipse from doing this?  Other than remembering to shut it down, of course.

I can't remember the version of Eclipse but I can find out if it's important.  I believe it's the newest version.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, sharing a workspace (via Dropbox or any other mechanism) is not recommended. In fact, it's highly recommended *against*. Workspaces are designed to be specific to a machine, but projects are designed to be shared.

Comment: I understand your point but I'm not sure how it's a bad idea.  Especially since I want the same environment on multiple machines.  And, I'm the only one using each machine.  I do something similar with my bash profile.  I store those settings in DropBox so that each machine I log in with SSH, I get the same setup.

Comment: The difference is that a shell profile isn't typically updated automatically, behind the scenes. And it probably doesn't contain machine-specific stuff. An Eclipse workspace has all of those characteristics and I promise it will cause headaches eventually if you share them. It's not difficult to share *projects* and use Eclipse built-in capabilities for abstracting environmental stuff so that each workspace that includes a project treats it exactly the same.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't normally use Eclipse so maybe that's why I haven't noticed it.  But I share shell profiles, projects, etc. all the time.  Never had issues.  But I suppose I haven't been sharing machine specific details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the 'Workspace save interval'. Change the setting in the Preferences on the 'General > Workspace' page.